# Error 503 in J2EE Preview at local host

Tags: servlets

I'm simply trying to insert a row of data to a database using a serve-let in eclipse. I'm using the server J2EE Preview at local host. I even tried using apache tomcat v7.0. But every time 'HTTP ERROR 503' comes on the web page.

This is my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    public class trying extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            try {

                Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");
                Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();


                String sql = "insert into user values ('bandiiii', '123')";
                myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                System.out.print("done");

            }catch( Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions printed?  What is in the Tomcat logs?

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably your application is down or the application is trying to hit a server that is not up and running.

[Http Status code 503](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):
simply means that service is unavailable.

**Troubleshooting:**

Check if your server & Oracle servers are up and running on the specified ports.